# Class Intent in AndroidStudio not recognized when starting an activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m currently trying to start another activity by pressing a button, but it gives me this error:

**None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied: 
public constructor Intent(p0: Context!, p1: Class<*>!) defined in android.content.Intent
public constructor Intent(p0: String!, p1: Uri!) defined in android.content.Intent**

The code I´m using worked previously on the project, but right now it doesn´t. My code is this, and fails when pressing help_button:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_study.*
import android.content.Intent

class StudyFragment: Fragment() {

    private val cardsViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(CardsViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (cardsViewModel.answered == true) {
            answer_button.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            difficulty_buttons.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        answer_button.setOnClickListener {
            cardsViewModel.answered = true
            question_text_view.text = resources.getString(R.string.answer_text)
            answer_button.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            difficulty_buttons.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        help_button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this, HelpActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_study, container, false)
        return view
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): StudyFragment {
            return StudyFragment()
        }
    }

}
```

Is there anything I´m not importing?

Comment: you're inside fragment pass _context_ instead of _this_ , below is right answer... you can't pass context with _this_ keyword you've to call _context_ when you are doing fragment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be `startActivity(Intent(requireContext(), HelpActivity::class.java))`